# DLL export virtual function errors

Tags: c++, dll

I have a library which I need to export to DLL. If I mark virtual methods of a base class with  `__declspec(dllimport) /  __declspec(dllimport)`, the subclasses throw:

```
unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall...**
```

Here is a how my code looks like:

globals.h

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#ifdef _EXPORTING
#define MYAPI __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYAPI __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
#else
#define MYAPI 
#endif
```

base.h

```
class BaseClass :boost::noncopyable
{
    public:
        virtual MYAPI  void DoSmth1() {
        };

        virtual MYAPI void Dosmth2() {

        };
};
```

subclass.h:

```
class SubClass: public BaseClass 
{
    public:
        MYAPI  void DoSmth1();
        MYAPI void Dosmth2() ;
};
```

Should virtual methods be exported differently?

Comment: How can you expect to export methods but not classes?

Comment: Don't you have to export the whole class. Not just a few members?

Comment: Based on Microsoft docs I can export only methods.

Comment: Put MYAPI after class to export / import the class.

Comment: But in such a case I export the whole class, which I want to avoid.

Comment: Can you just hide the class in the implementation and use some different interface that exposes only what you want?

Comment: @drescherjm if what I am asking here were not possible I would consider this, but as I said MS state it is completely doable.

Comment: I think you can do what you are trying with static members but not virtual functions.

Comment: Btw exporting the whole class throws the same error but for all the methods.

Comment: Did you read this yet: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81h27t8c.aspx

Comment: Yes I did.That is why I believe it is doable.It is not stated there I can't export virtual method.From the other side they don't show how it is done when subclass is involved.

Comment: Exporting a class also requires exporting the v-table if the class has virtual methods.  You must therefore apply the __declspec(attribute) to the entire class, not just the methods.  A significant secondary problem is that base classes must be exported as well, for the same reason.  It isn't clear whether you've got a problem with the boost class, you obfuscated the error message too much.

Comment: I just tried to wrap both the base and the sub class with the export.Still getting it for all the member methods of the class.

Comment: Removed boost base class.The same thing....

Comment: Compiles fine for me, and I removed the boost base class since I don't have boost to hand.

Comment: Wait,I think it was  really really dumb mistake.I was on .exe mode.Switched to .lib and it compiled.So it means I can't keep this syntax if the lib is compiled as executable.